# How do you deal with ', single quote in person's names in php, javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I noticed that some of name entries, like O'Rourke or O'reilly breaks javascript in some cases. I wonder how you deal with it. I pull these names out of PHP/MYSQL and put them in javascript.

Do you replace them before entering to database or after pulling out of database?

Thanks in advance

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'First Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Last Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'email');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Parent email 1');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Parent email 2');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Advisor');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Active');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Edit');
        //data.addColumn('number', '');
        data.addRows([
     <?php
   if(count($items))
   {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            foreach($advisors as $key=>$advisor)
            {
                if($item['advisor']==$advisor['id'])
                {
                    $ad=$advisor['last_name'];
                }
            }
            $active_icon = ($item['active']=='1'?'tick':'cross');
            $editlink = anchor('auth/admin/members/form/'.$item['id'],$this->bep_assets->icon('pencil'));
            echo "['".$item['first_name']."', '".$item['last_name']."', '".$item['email']
            ."', '".$item['parent_email1']."', '".$item['parent_email2']."', '".$ad."', '".$this->bep_assets->icon($active_icon)."','".$editlink."'],";
        }
   }

    ?>

        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, allowHtml:true});
      }
```

Comment: What is your implementation? You may have to escape them or turn them to HTML entities.

Comment: The funny thing is: If your data source contained typographical (i.e. “correct”) apostrophes (’) instead of the ugly compromise known as straight apostrophes ('), you would never have known there was something wrong…

Comment: What are you using to put values into the database?

Answer (score 2):

You're going through a lot of messy and error-prone string-appending work just to output a javascript variable.  What you should do instead is build the data structure you want in PHP (an array of arrays) and then use `json_encode()` to emit a javascript-compatible literal.  All quotes and such will be automatically escaped by the encoder.

```
$itemOutput = array();
if(count($items)) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        foreach($advisors as $key=>$advisor) {
            if($item['advisor']==$advisor['id']) {
                $ad=$advisor['last_name'];
            }
        }
        $active_icon = ($item['active']=='1'?'tick':'cross');
        $editlink = anchor('auth/admin/members/form/'.$item['id'],$this->bep_assets->icon('pencil'));
        $itemOutput[] = array(
            $item['first_name'],
            $item['last_name'],
            $item['email'],
            $item['parent_email'],
            $item['parent_email2'],
            $ad,
            $this->beep_assets->icon($active_icon),
            $editLink
        );
    }
}
echo "data.addRows(" . json_encode($itemOutput) . ");" ;
```

If you have an object or an associative array, it gets emitted as a javascript object:

```
echo json_encode( 
    array( 'a'=>'aa', 'b'=>'bb'),
    array( 'c'=>'cc', 'd'=>'dd')
);
==> [{"a":"aa","b":"bb"},{"c":"cc","d":"dd"}]
```

Comment: Great solution. Way better than using `addslashes`. This way you won’t even have to build the JS array using string concatenation and can, instead, write a native PHP array directly and have everything taken care of automatically.

Comment: I tried json_encode($item['first_name']), but it still give an error.

Comment: rewrite the answer.  When you say "it still give an error", what error do you mean?